# Can /ask redirect to /questions/ask?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

`/ask` currently 404s. It would be nice to have this URL redirect to the ask page.

Chrome (and probably Firefox) tends to autocomplete stackoverflow/*.stackexchange.com sites without a URL path appended, so just starting to type "sta" readily fills in just the domain name.

From there, if you press <kbd>End</kbd> and then start to type "/quest"... you'll be met with various question URLs you've visited or pasted, but these URLs will all contain "/questions/.......", not just "/questions/" so you can hit <kbd>End</kbd> again and type "ask". If I manually typed "ask" myself, it would very probably be bumped out of the URL history if I eg viewed a question 10 times in a day or similar.

On the other hand, you can autocomplete StackOverflow or one of the StackExchange sites, hit <kbd>End</kbd> and then typing `/ask` is just 4 more characters.

Would be really nice if I specifically have a question I want to ask and don't want to be distracted by the front page.

Comment: Do we really need to make it easier for people to quickly ask questions? If loading the front page takes too much time; it's likely the necessary investigation and debugging hasn't been done by the asker, either.

Comment: or.... you can just bookmark /questions/ask and use that? Feels like a hassle to code it into the site, for virtually no benefit (+ what Rob said is very appropriate too: If you skip the front page, are you SURE you made your due diligence at checking for your answer on here?)

Comment: @Rob: it takes about 5 seconds for my old (2007) computer load the homepage, then 2 more seconds for me to move the mouse to the "ask" button and click it, and 3 more seconds for the ask page to load. It takes 4.5 seconds for the ask page to load directly in a new tab.

Comment: @i336_ Considering askers should spend *hours* researching and attempting to solve their own problem before asking a question here, is an extra 5.5 seconds *really* an issue here?

Comment: @Patrice: I forgot bookmarking prioritizes URLs, thanks for that idea - it surfaces straight to the top now after I hit End and input "/q". Also, I make sure to keep an eye on the suggestion box as I type questions, and I do search for them before I ask.

Comment: @Rob: No, I can't deny that :) I guess I'm sensitive to latency spikes and glitches, and I forget others' computers are faster than mine sometimes and get irrelevant ideas about how to speed things up that aren't an issue for other people.

Comment: I don't always ask questions, but when I do... this would be nice. Also for providing links in comments under answers that are actually new questions informing them that if they have a new question, they should use the [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page. (I would have saved 10 characters in that link, which I could have used for more useful information, not to mention the 168 characters in this parenthetical statement).

Comment: If you're so concerned about those 5 seconds you're wasting to ask a question, why not just bookmark the page? That's a quicker process than any site change will ever be.

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for this suggestion - Patrice suggested it a few comments ago - and it works really well!